# Do I need to create a one property per one android application in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I already made a several android application and I want it to be connected in one google analytics account. Is that possible to do?? if it is, please help me on how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a GA4 property and use the same Measurement ID.

However it doesn't make much sense, I would make separate priorities for each app.

Comment: Thanks Sir. i just wanna know how many app that one property can handle? even if they are different app will it still work?? BTW Thank you

Comment: There are no such limits, you will have data from different apps.

Comment: Thanks Sir. When I try to use it on one of my app and I just follow the SDK setup instructions under google analytics data stream and it works on the first app but there's a delay. My problem is when I to make another data stream to connect my second app I didn't know why its not showing any users in realtime function of google analytics.I just follow what I do in the first app nothing more and less..Can you enlighten me on that problem.. Thank You